# How can I display different text from a different div on mouse click?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

How can I display different text from a different div on mouse click?
So for each click on the pie it should show different text from divs.
How can I do this?

This is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/r6p7E/19/
But I want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/2ehdW/

```
click: function(event) {
    if(event.point.selected) {
        $("#content").hide();
    }else {
        $("#content").show();
        $("#content").html(event.point.name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood you need implement a kind of a map to convert selected chart data to the proper div id and get the inner text of this div.

I don't know what divs you have so for example: http://jsfiddle.net/r6p7E/21/

```
click: function(event) {
  alert($('#data'+event.point.name).html());
  $('#testDiv').show();
}
```

In this case the map is processed as `'#data'+event.point.name`

But you can use js hashtable for a complex map.

Comment: Yes ! Thanks ! Something like this I want !

Comment: @OOOO I was actually about to post this [**sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/2ehdW/1/) but seeing it is almost the same as phil's answer, I did not do it. But you can use it for reference.

Comment: @Harry : Yes, was simple, but i don't know too much javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The event passed to click contains event.point which contains both properties name and y which can give you the data that is shown on click in http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/2ehdW/

Example of setting the div to show the name of the browser:

```
click: function(event) {
    $('#testDiv').show().text(event.point.name);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qXTbr/

For your code I believe you'd want:

```
click: function(event) {
    if(!event.point.selected) {
        $("#content").hide();
    }else {
        $("#content").show();
        $("#content").html(event.point.name)
    }
}
```

As you want the data to be hidden when it's not selected rather than when it is selected